# Вопрос про шаблонизатор dle

Tags: php, dle

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `".USERPREFIX."_text`");

$tpl->load_template( 'text.tpl' );

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $title .= $row['title'];
    $tpl->set("{title}", $title);
}

$tpl->compile( 'content' );
$tpl->clear();
```

как выводить каждый заголовок с файла?

Вот файл text.tpl

```
<div class="title">{title}</div>
```

выводились все заголовки но так

```
<div class"title">
Тевес: "Не работал так много со времён игры в "Боке".
Маротта: "Мы должны продать двоих нападающих".
Кьеллини: "Мне и в голову бы не пришло уйти из "Ювентуса".
</div>
```

мне нужно чтобы каждый заголовок был на новом div'е

```
<div class"title">
Тевес: "Не работал так много со времён игры в "Боке".
</div>
<div class"title">
Маротта: "Мы должны продать двоих нападающих".
</div>    
<div class"title">
Кьеллини: "Мне и в голову бы не пришло уйти из "Ювентуса".
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так, только храни свои title в массиве

```
{foreach from=$title item="t"}
<div class="title">
{$t}
</div>
{/foreach}
```